# How to add multiple parameters in where clause not dependent on each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I need a query with 5 parameters such as...

> name,surname,birthplace,dateofbirth,ID.

The parameter should have null as default and not dependent on each other. When running the report i should filter for example only with ID  etc. Sometimes i could filter with 2 parameters or more

Answer (score 0):

The SQL will be along the line of

```
Select
your columns

from some_table

where 

(@name = some_table.name_column or @name is null)
and
(@surname = some_table.surname_column or @surname is null)
and
(@birth_place = some_table.birth_place_column or @birth_place is null)
and
(@dateofbirth= some_table.dateofbirth_column or @dateofbirth is null)
and
(@ID= some_table.ID_column or @ID is null)
```

now in SSRS, allow nulls for all of your parameters.. of course.. you need to select at least one parameter value else you are effectively returning everything from your table.. which I'm sure is something you don't want.

Comment: I've tried but when i run the report the parameter @ID isn't checked. I've add NULL as default in parameter properties.

Comment: use the above code as is in SQL to see if it works. Declare all the parameters set default values as null for everything except ID and see if the query returns anything

Comment: Hey i've build the report from scratch again and i've used your query and when running the report if i fill 1 parameter and view report i'm getting a error to enter a value for the other parameter.

Comment: Have you set Allow Nulls for your parameters in the new report?

Answer (score 0):

[ID and Firstname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SvfM.png)

please see ID and voornaam means firstname not checked

[Null selected in paramter properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCLz9.png)

[default null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkhs3.png)

Comment: please add any comments by editing your questions.. not by answering your own questions with more information

Comment: Hi Harry, I've tried your query but for example if i type a value in parameter name when viewing report it gives me nothing no data in report. What could be the issue?

Comment: can you show some sample data and your actual query?